# How to lag series of a list and applying a function to each series

Tags: r, statistics

I have a list containing 29 time series -- list is called "lRet"

I need to lag all series by one time period and compute the first auto correlation. I then need to store these 29 numbers in the 6th colomn of a matrix.

```
> head(lRet$TRV)
           TRV.Adjusted
2018-01-03    0.3177055
2018-01-04    0.0000000
2018-01-05   -0.1814193
2018-01-08   -0.5386908
2018-01-09    0.7729854
2018-01-10   -0.2721412

> head(lag(lRet$TRV))
           TRV.Adjusted
2018-01-03           NA
2018-01-04    0.3177055
2018-01-05    0.0000000
2018-01-08   -0.1814193
2018-01-09   -0.5386908
2018-01-10    0.7729854
```

The autocorrelation is simply the correlation between the two series above. I need to do this for all 29 series ( the above is just 1).

```
DescStat[,6] <- diag(cor(lRet[-1], lag(lRet, 1)[-1]))
```

where I removed the first observation since the lag operator generates a "NA" as the first entry. This doesn't work because `"x has to be numeric"` (error in R). I use `diag` because `cor` produces a matrix and I only want the correlation with the stock itself - not the correlation between stocks.

I then tried to change all values in the list to numeric values with "as.numeric":

```
DescStat[,6] <- diag(cor(sapply(lRet, as.numeric)[-1], sapply(lag(as.numeric(lRet),1))[-1]))
```

but I get the error "(list) cannot be coerced to type 'double'" which I interpret as my list still being a list.....

I feel like I am so close.. what am I doing wrong? Is there an incredibly simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. The answer is much simpler. Just use `sapply()` to apply the function on each element in the list. Since your list has returns on stocks as individual elements, you don't need to use `diag()`. Just use the `sapply()` to apply the correlation code you have on each element in the list. `sapply()` returns a dataframe, so it will fill the rows in the six column with the values.

```r
DescStat[,6] <- sapply(lRet, function(x) x <- cor(x[-1], lag(x, 1)[-1]))
```